# Uploadify fails to open file browser?

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I have an implementation of uploadify running on top of a PHP application.  It was working just fine on my test machine.  However, I just uploaded it on to my production machine and it is failing.  Uploadify correctly replaces the input field and presents the button.  However, when the button is clicked nothing happens.  It completely fails to open the file browser.  No error.  Just quiet fail.  Any ideas what could be going wrong here?  Something in the php.ini?  A mod I haven't downloaded?  I'm at a loss.

**Edit**: When I follow the links through and load the uploadify.swf flash directly it works fine.  The button shows, click on it and the file browser appears.  But when I load it in the web page, it doesn't work.  The button shows, but clicking on it yields nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It failed do to my calling the script across domains.  My `$.uploadify` call looked for the script at `example.com` when it was being called from `www.example.com`.  This caused it to fail.

If you encounter this problem, ensure your scripts don't attempt to call across subdomains.

Comment: Thank you for encountering this exact problem and providing me with a solution... albeit 2 years later :)