# Uploadify unknown error

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I cant seem to get Uploadify (2.1.4) to work, In Google Chrome Inspector the console shows no errors during initialization, however, clicking on the select files button results in nothing happening and pressing the upload button results in:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLObjectElement> has no method 'startFileUpload'
```

I have no Idea where to look, the weird thing is it only shows an error when any button or function is called, however the .uploadify(); is working fine.

I am using:
 - JQuery 1.7.1
 - Twitter Bootstrap (in this case the twipsy & modal javascript files)

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#uploadPopup").modal({
        backdrop: "static",
        keyboard: false
    });

    var uploadBox = '<div id="status-message">Select some files to upload:</div>\
                    <div id="fileQueue"></div>\
                    <input id="fileUploadSelector" type="file" name="Filedata" />';
    var uploadInProgress = false;

    $("#uploadphoto").click(function(){
        $("#uploadPopup h3").html("Video Uploader");
        $("#uploadPopup .modal-body").html(uploadBox);

        $('#fileUploadSelector').uploadify({
            'uploader': 'static/flash/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script': 'www.example.com/script.php',
            'cancelImg': 'static/images/uploadify/cancel.png',
            'multi': true,
            'auto': false,
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.bmp',
            'fileDesc': 'Image Files (.JPG, .GIF, .PNG, .BMP)',
            'queueID': 'fileQueue',
            'queueSizeLimit': 100,
            'simUploadLimit': 2,
            'removeCompleted': true,
            'buttonText': 'Select Files',
            'onSelectOnce': function (event, data) {
                $('#status-message').text(data.filesSelected + ' files have been added to the queue.');
            },
            'onAllComplete': function (event, data) {
                $('#status-message').text(data.filesUploaded + ' files uploaded, ' + data.errors + ' errors.');
                uploadInProgress = false;
                $("#uploadMedia").button('reset');
            },
            'onClearQueue': function (event, data) {
                $('#status-message').text('Upload Cancelled');
                uploadInProgress = false;
                $("#uploadMedia").button('reset');
            }
        });

        $("#uploadPopup").modal({
            backdrop: "static",
            keyboard: false
        });
    });

    $("#uploadMedia").live('click', function(){
        $("#fileUploadSelector").uploadifyUpload();
        uploadInProgress = true;
    });

    $("#cancelUpload").live('click', function(){
        var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel the upload?");
            if(answer) {
                $("#fileUploadSelector").uploadifyClearQueue();
                $('#uploadPopup').modal('hide');
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
    });
});
</script>
```

And the HTML part:

```
<div class="btn success" id="uploadphoto">Upload Photo</div>

<div id="uploadPopup" class="modal hide">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>Photo viewer</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn primary" id="uploadMedia" data-toggle="Uploading..">Upload</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn secondary" id="cancelUpload">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Explanation:
 - A user presses the #uploadphoto button and a modal appears (during this step also the uploadify initializes)
 - The modal contains a button (#uploadMedia) which, when pressed, starts the upload.
 - pressing the cancel button (#cancelUpload) cancels the upload and closes the modal

Please note this is still some prototype coding, cleanup still has to take place.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: The error you're getting basically says that you are using an invalid object to call .uploadifyUpload().  I'm not sure why that is, but my guess is that the object returned from the $("#fileUploadSelector") in the $("#uplaodMedia").live() function isn't the correct object. I think if you were to set auto to true, the upload would work fine but for whatever reason your reference to the fileUploadSelector is incorrect.  Can you post the rest of your code so I can have a better look at it?

Comment: well the fact is, it wont even let me select the files I want to upload when I press the uploadify button (which is converted into the swf with success) which is currently the main issue, as I think everything else is kinda related to it. Also, besides this piece of javascript there isn't really anything else, some html but I dont think thats going to help unfortunatly.

Comment: Set auto to true and see if it lets you select the files

Comment: Tried it, without result

Comment: I'm at a loss than, the rest of it looks good.  If you post the html for me so I can just copy it and try and help debug that would be good.

Comment: added the HTML, you will need to add the bootstrap (1.4) files yourself for it to work though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7258/discussion-between-xorinzor-and-xcrkx-typhoon)

Comment: http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/4804/uploadify-stops-working-in-ie/p1

Comment: @xorinzor-Are you inluding bootstrap modal buttons too?

Comment: @DotNetter we just fixed it, pretty lame error :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Uploadify fails to open file browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012417/uploadify-fails-to-open-file-browser)

This guy had the same problem, looks like it's an issue with calling scripts across subdomains.
Glad I could help!